# Replacing the current fragment by removing the previous one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to be able to go through fragments like this: **A->B->C1**
When I'm on **C1** I need to replace it with **C2**, but when I press back I should be taken back to **B** instead of **C1**.
I'm able to do this like this:

```
    String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.popBackStack();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.mainActivity_container, fragment, tag);
    ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    ft.commit();
```

The problem is that while I'm changing from **C1** to **C2**, fragment **B** gets it's **onCreateInnerView** method called.

I need to be able to do something like this: **A->B->C1->C2->C1->C2** and by pressing back in **C2** I should go to **B**

How to execute replacement without recreating fragment **B**?

Comment: so you are expecting flow like : A-> B-> C1 -> C2 (now you press back than it will) -> B and so on.. Right ?

Comment: Yes. It can also go like A->B->C2->C1 and when I press back on C1 in this case I still need to go back to B.

Comment: Okay got it. so while moving to B -> C1 and B -> C2 don't add ' manager.popBackStack();' and also addToBackStack(null).

Comment: While being in C2 I could change to C1, then back to C2 and do it multiple times. So in this case it wouldn't work.

Comment: wait i am creating few methods for you. if possible please post your method for moving from B-> C1 , C1->C2 and also for B->C2.

Comment: Transaction from B to C1 or C2 has the same code just without manager.popBackStack()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172509/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-smart).

Comment: You can handle the `onBackPressed()` event and replace whatever is the current fragment to fragment **B**.

Comment: @KlingKlang, can you provide a working code sample that should be placed in the onBackPressed()?

Comment: Something like the 4 last lines shown in your code above.

Comment: @KlingKlang, so code's behaviour changes depending on the location it is called?

Comment: That's what I would try.

Comment: @Kling Klang, well it does seem like a possible hack if I just remove C1 and C2 fragments from stack on back key. Even though this approach is non-intuitive and requires additional code for each case.

Comment: @KlingKlang, since I couldn't find any other better approach, can you post your comment as answer so I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the onBackPressed() event and replace whatever is the current fragment to fragment B.

Comment: I ended up using this approach. I've written method popToFragment(Class<?> clazz); Where I just keep popping fragments until the last one in back stack is my specified class. I still wish there was a more intuitive replace approach.

Answer (score 0):

First thing You don't need to `popupstack` while moving to fragment. Because It will call your last stack's fragment `onViewCreated` method.

While moving to **B -> C1** , **B -> C2** and  **C1 -> C2**  :

- Need to add Back stack `null`
- Remove popupbackstack

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: Going B->C1->C2 and pressing back I go back to C1 instead of B

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be help you,
Just replace two line ,

```
  manager.popBackStack();//Remove this line
  ft.replace(R.id.mainActivity_container, fragment);//Remove 3rd param in this line
  ft.addToBackStack(tag);//Remove this line
```

**EDITED**
  you can also try this

```
 public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();  

     for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
     Fragment currentFragment = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainActivity_container);
        if(currentFragment != B){
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainActivity_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: Won't this just remove all fragments? I'll loose A and B :(

Comment: @SMGhost I think this is the final solution.

Comment: Sorry. Your answer misses the point of not reinflating fragment B while doing a switch among C1 and C2. Another issue is that this is no longer generic method if B is hardcoded or I otherwise have to track it elsewhere.